# Can't read variable inside try catch

Tags: java, variables, try-catch

```
String selectedDate = "2012-" + createdMonth
        + "-" + createdDay;

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

try {
    Date createdDate = dateFormat.parse(selectedDate);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
    "Here is your new booking schedule:\n "
        + "Timeslot: "
        + selectedTimeslot + "\n"
        + "Date: " + createdDate + "\n"
        + "Continue?",
    "Booking Confirmation",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
    options, options[1]);
```

The problem is that createdDate in the JOptionPane can't be resolved to a variable. why is that? I've tried everything like initializing the Date object outside the try catch but it still doesn't work. Help!

Comment: Given the sheer amount of redundant white space, are there any parts of the code left out from the middle?

Comment: Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`. `MM` means months; `mm` means minutes. See the API documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 5):

Because the variable is out of scope once the try block is completed.  Move you jOptionPane code to inside the try block or move the createDate declaration outside the try block.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the variable inside the try-catch block, which is its own scope. Outside the try block, the variable is 'out of scope', so 'doesnt exist' at the later point.

Answer (score 0):

the scope of the variable is inside the try { } since it is where it is declared. You can do something like this:

```
Date createDate;
try
{
    createDate = dateFormat.parse(selectedDate);
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable inside the scope of the try.  You used "Date createdDate = ...." which means that once outside of the scope of the try { .. } it won't exist any longer. Make sure you declare it out of the scope of the try and see if that works!

Comment: dammit you need to type fast on this webiste! :)

Comment: ... or write great answers or pick harder questions :-)